# Why would a MySQL database show up in SHOW DATABASES but not in the information_schema table?

Tags: mysql, database-schema, mysql5, mysql-5.6

I am noticing a very strange issue with my MySQL 5.6.23.

Why would a MySQL database show up in SHOW DATABASES but not in the information_schema table?

I was trying to find out the sizes of all my databases by this query that has been floating around StackOverflow, and that's when I noticed that my main database is not showing up with this query because it is not in information_schema at all  :

```
SELECT table_schema                                        "DB Name", 
Round(Sum(data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 1) "DB Size in MB" 
FROM   information_schema.tables 
GROUP  BY table_schema;
```

Could anyone please shed some light?

Thanks
IS

Comment: Are there any tables in the database or is it empty?

Comment: There are tables, and you can run normal SQL queries on it no problem, like SELECT, INSERT, etc.